# Why there's no tcp_westwood?

Tags: kernel

I am on Ubuntu server 12.04

```
$ sudo cat /etc/issue /etc/lsb-release
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"

$ uname -a
Linux vps2 2.6.32-042stab078.28 #1 SMP Mon Jul 8 10:17:22 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

According to this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/tcp.7.html

there should be tcp_westwood, but I can't find on my server:

```
$ sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_westwood
-bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_westwood: No such file or directory

$ sudo tail /proc/sys/net/ipv4/*congest*
==> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_allowed_congestion_control <==
cubic reno

==> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control <==
cubic reno

==> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control <==
cubic
```

So how could I enable tcp westwood for 12.04 lts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read again it will tell you the reason:

> tcp_westwood (Boolean; **default: disabled**; Linux *2.4.26/2.6.3 to 2.6.13*)
>                 Enable   TCP   Westwood+   congestion  control  algorithm.   TCP
>                 Westwood+ is a sender-side only modification  of  the  TCP  Reno
>                 protocol  stack that optimizes the performance of TCP congestion
>                 control.  It is based on end-to-end bandwidth estimation to  set
>                 congestion  window  and  slow start threshold after a congestion
>                 episode.  Using this estimation, TCP Westwood+ adaptively sets a
>                 slow  start  threshold  and a congestion window which takes into
>                 account  the  bandwidth  used  at   the   time   congestion   is
>                 experienced.   TCP  Westwood+  significantly  increases fairness
>                 with respect to TCP Reno in wired networks and  throughput  over
>                 wireless links.

So, what happens here?

1. By default, that option is not activated in the kernel.
2. Was meant implemented in kernels 2.4.26/2.6.3 to 2.6.13.
3. There should be alternatives more recent to what you try to do.

Options:

1. Not using this.
2. Build your own kernel and activate the option.
3. Using the `-generic` kernel.
4. Installing the `user-mode-linux` package.

Comment: I am trying to improve tcp in a lossy network. I found many online tutorials mention that tcp_westwood is better than ubuntu's default.

Comment: @est as I said, either, don't use it, or re-build the kernel with the option.

Comment: thanks. Is is possible to enable it by `modprobe` or something or the only option is to re-compile kernel?

Comment: Hi, I found [this](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=tcp_westwood.ko%20site%3Apackages.ubuntu.com%2Fprecise%2F). What's the safest way to install and enable it?

Comment: @est I think you got a winner there ;)

Comment: Sorry but I think `user-mode-linux` is [a VM](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/)? I don't want to make the serve stack too complex. Is it safe to install packages like `linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic` to a critical server?

Comment: @est the "disable" is done within the kernel code, since it's part of the kernel you'd have to enable it at compile, I think.

Comment: @est according to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tcp_westwood.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any) the generic kernel has the module built activated.

Comment: @est that module seem to be designed for user-space use. You sure the guide you are following is for a "server".

Comment: @Braiam yes, but what's the best practice to install linux kernel images? I don't want get my server unbootable after kernel upgrade... btw I am on [LTS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tcp_westwood.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any). Other info about the server can be found on my question

Comment: @est you are telling me that "Ubuntu server", I presume you want it for a "server" by the comments until now. The best option is *up to you*. I would go with the `-generic` deb package if the main use of the "server" isn't desktop. If I try to keep things tight I may select building the kernel. The final desition is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just available via Module.
In Ubuntu > 18.04 just set sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=westwood like the creator of the Westwood instructions:
[Instruction Official](https://c3lab.poliba.it/Westwood:Linux)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1291040)